# Eigenfunction of Momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, momentum, eigenvalue

I've been having trouble solving this question given by one of my professors.

> If eigenfunction of momentum operator is $e^{-x^3}$, then calculate its eigenvalue.

So far, if $p = i(h/2\pi)(d/dx)$, if I differentiate the given function and put it in this equation, I get $p = 3i(h/2\pi)(x^2)(e^{-x^3})$, and accordingly, $3i(h/2\pi)$ should be my eigenvalue. But I'm confused, shouldn't it be a real value? What am I missing?

Comment: I think that, if you have quoted accurately,  your teacher is confused. The expression is not an eigenfunction of $\hat p$.

Comment: *Ex falso quodlibet*...

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. Recall the definition of eigenvalue: a scalar constant $\lambda$ such that

$$Tf=\lambda f$$

where $T$ is the operator (linear transformation) and $f$ is one of its eigenfunctions. So you're looking for a $\lambda$ such that $\hat p f(x)=\lambda f(x)$, more specifically

$$\hat p (e^{-x^3})=\lambda e^{-x^3}$$

where $\hat p =-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$ (note the negative sign). It appears you computed $\hat p f$ (not $\hat p$, double check what you wrote). You found something of the form

$$\hat p(e^{-x^3})=cx^2e^{-x^3}$$

or more abstractly

$$Tf=cg(x)f$$

where $g(x)$ is not a constant. Does that look like the eigenvalue equation to you? What would the eigenvalue be, $\lambda=c$ or $\lambda =cg(x)$?

Neither. The RHS is not strictly a constant times the original function, therefore $e^{-x^3}$ is not an eigenfunction of the operator $\hat p=-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$ and there is no eigenvalue. Maybe it's a trick question, maybe it's poorly phrased, maybe it was copied down wrong. The fact remains.

Keep in mind there is no general requirement for eigenvalues to be real numbers. Eigenvalues are real for Hermitian operators, which are probably most or all of what you'll use in an intro level quantum mechanics course, but your professor could give you arbitrary non-Hermitian operators for practice and they might not have real eigenvalues. I'd recommend you focus more on rembering the definition of what and eigenvalue is and computing it carefully rather than whether it is real or complex.

Comment: Understood, thanks. Any suggestion on what I can do with this problem right now? Even if I differentiate the equation simply, I get -3(x^2) times the original function.

Comment: What you can do with this problem is circle the $x^2$ factor, tell your teacher than the given function is not an eigenfunction of the given operator, and hope they word things better next time.